# can't add flasfka package path in Mac

Tags: flask, apache-kafka

I need to use Kafka with flask-socketIO for a project. So I decided to use [flasfka](https://github.com/travel-intelligence/flasfka) app that does push/pull to Kafka through http.

Following the instruction, I added `FLASFKA_CONFIG` path in environment

```
export FLASFKA_CONFIG=/etc/flasfka.conf.py
```

But when I run `flasfka-serve` to start `flasfka`, I get error

> flasfka-serve: command not found

I even added the above export command in my `.bash_profile` file and restarted the terminal but I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the [documentation](https://github.com/travel-intelligence/flasfka) is WRONG.

It says

```
pip install kafka
```

instead it should be

```
pip install flasfka
```